# How to use multiple Stack Navigator in React Native?

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

I'm new to React-Native.
I have a Stack Navigator in my **router.js** file:

```
const Containers = createStackNavigator({
  Tabs: {
    screen: Tabs,
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false
    }
  }
}, {
  headerMode: 'none'
});

export default createAppContainer(Containers);
```

In one of the tabs, there is a Flat-List. If the user clicks one of the items in the list, Edit Item screen should be opened.
Therefore, I tried:

```
const ListStack = createStackNavigator({
  MyList: {
    screen: MyList,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: null,
    }),
  },
  EditItem: {
    screen: EditItem,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: null,
      tabBarVisible: false,
      gesturesEnabled: false
    }),
  },
});
```

Then, I added ListStack into Containers as:

```
ListStack: {
    screen: ListStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false
    }
  },
```

In MyList class, there is:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('EditItem', {id: this.props.id})}>
```

Also in EditItem class:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
```

But now, Tabs won't be rendered on the bottom of the screen. I can only see the items on the list.
What is the reason and how can I solve it?

Comment: MyList and EditItem  Add screens in Tabs.